# Infusionsoft API to trigger confirmation email

Tags: php, wordpress, infusionsoft

All I want to do is get infusionsoft to send the confirmation email to people when they sign up. Currently I can not find a method that would trigger that. I have tried creating campaigns and goals therein, and using the Funnel API to attempt to trigger that. I have used the optIn api to manually opt someone in. And Thus far nothing works. I mean I can see the email status change from non-marketable to unconfirmed, and I can see the person in a goal as well. So the api's themselves are working. However no email is being dispatched from infusion like I'd assume it should be.

Idea's?

Answer (score 0):

While the email status is unconfirmed, trigger them to start a campaign by the API goal and in your campaign add an email confirmation request node.

Here is the Infusionsoft help article on creating an email confirmation request node in the campaign builder:

http://help.infusionsoft.com/userguides/campaigns-and-broadcasts/campaign-sequence-guide/email-confirmation-sequence

Do not skip step 6. Not marking the node as ready will prevent emails from being sent.

Also make sure the campaign is published.